# Tidymodels troubleshooting - "Warning message: There are new levels in a factor: NA"

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels

I am trying out tidymodels on the penguins dataset. I want to build a recipe and then compare different imputing methods (knn in example below). I get the following error when trying to build a model:

```
Warning message:
There are new levels in a factor: NA
```

I have tried different solutions (using step_novel(), step_unknown(), step_naomit()) but none seem to work. The only thing that works is if I remove/handle all missing data prior to creating the recipe, but that defeats the purpose of using preprocessing with recipes, right? Full code below.

```
# penguins dataset tidymodels

# libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(workflowsets)
library(skimr)
library(DataExplorer)
library(SmartEDA)
library(dlookr)
library(dataMaid)
library(GGally)

# import
data <- penguins

# split
set.seed(1) 
data_split <- data %>% initial_split(prop = 0.75, strata = species)
data_train <- training(data_split)
data_test <- testing(data_split)

# model recipe
recipe <- recipe(species ~ ., data = data_train) %>% 
  step_log(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_corr(all_numeric_predictors(), threshold = 0.9) %>%  
  step_zv(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())

# recipe with knn imputing
recipe_knn_impute <- recipe %>% 
  step_impute_knn(all_predictors())

# Apply processing to test and training data
baked_data_train <- recipe_knn_impute %>% prep() %>% bake(data_train)
baked_data_test <- recipe_knn_impute %>% prep() %>% bake(data_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

[We suggest doing imputation first](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/articles/Ordering.html); otherwise all of the other operations are affected by the missing data. This warning probably comes from the dummy variable creation (since they are still missing at that point).

The warnings go away if you impute first:

```r
# penguins dataset tidymodels

# libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(workflowsets)

# import
data <- penguins

# split
set.seed(1) 
data_split <- data %>% initial_split(prop = 0.75, strata = species)
data_train <- training(data_split)
data_test <- testing(data_split)

# model recipe
recipe_knn_impute <- 
  recipe(species ~ ., data = data_train) %>% 
  step_impute_knn(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_log(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_corr(all_numeric_predictors(), threshold = 0.9) %>%  
  step_zv(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())

# Apply processing to test and training data
baked_data_train <- recipe_knn_impute %>% prep() %>% bake(data_train)
baked_data_test <- recipe_knn_impute %>% prep() %>% bake(data_test)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>